# Replacing text in DOMDocument only works on the first few tags

Tags: php, html, replace, domdocument

I'm using PHP DOMDocument in order to loop through an html string like this:

```
$htmlString = "<section>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>text</h2>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
    </section>"
```

I want to replace each tag with a text value with a custom string (called $vueInterpolation), but for some reason.

**ONLY the first tag of each section is getting its contents replaced!**

**I want all the tags inside each section to be replaced!**

My method:

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$htmlString = mb_convert_encoding($htmlString, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);

$count = 0;
$keyPattern = 'ccpaRights';

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('section') as $section)
{

    // loop through each child of <section>
    foreach ($section->childNodes as $childNode)
    { 
         $nodeValue = trim($childNode->nodeValue); 

        if ($nodeValue === '')
        {
            continue; 
        }

        $count = $count + 1;
        $key = (string) $keyPattern.'Text'.$count;
        
        $vueInterpolation = ' {{ $t('.'"'.$key.'"'.' }} ';

        $newNode = $dom->createElement($childNode->nodeName, $vueInterpolation );

        $childNode->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $childNode);
    }
}


$dom->saveHTML($dom);
$dom->save(public_path('/temp/result.html'));
```

Just so you know, this is the results I'm getting (notice only first tag of each section was replaced).

```
<section>
    <p> {{ $t("ccpaRightsText1" }} </p>
    <p>text</p>
</section>
<section>
    <h2> {{ $t("ccpaRightsText2" }} </h2>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
</section>
```

And this is the results I want:

```
<section>
        <p> {{ $t("ccpaRightsText1" }} </p>
        <p> {{ $t("ccpaRightsText2" }} </p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2> {{ $t("ccpaRightsText3" }} </h2>
            <p> {{ $t("ccpaRightsText4" }} </p>
            <p> {{ $t("ccpaRightsText5" }} </p>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend:

1. Wrapping your HTML markup in a div tag so that your section tags belong to a parent element (otherwise broken results occur).  Remove the temporary tags after the replacing is done.
2. Using XPath to target the children of the section tags.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bIGRF))

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$count = 0;
foreach ($xpath->query('//section/*') as $node) {
    $node->nodeValue = ' {{ $t("ccpaRightsText' . ++$count . '" }} ';
}
echo substr($dom->saveHTML($dom), 5, -7);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error with your code because whitespaces between elements are considered nodes (#text).

[image]

So, try replace this line:

```php
$nodeValue = $childNode->nodeValue;
```

with this line:

```php
$nodeValue = trim($childNode->nodeValue);
```

The whole code:

```php
$htmlString = mb_convert_encoding($htmlString, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);

$count = 0;
$keyPattern = 'ccpaRights';

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('section') as $section)
{

    // loop through each child of <section>
    foreach ($section->childNodes as $childNode)
    { 
        $nodeValue = trim($childNode->nodeValue); 

        if ($nodeValue === '')
        {
            continue; 
        }

        $count = $count + 1;
        $key = (string) $keyPattern.'Text'.$count;
        
        $vueInterpolation = "{{ \$t(\"$key\") }}";
        
        $newNode = $dom->createElement($childNode->nodeName, $vueInterpolation);

        $childNode->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $childNode);
    }
}


echo $dom->saveHTML($dom);
```

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

I tried to use `for` loop instead of `foreach` and it works. I am trying to know the reason but I can't know it.

```php
$htmlString = mb_convert_encoding($htmlString, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);

$count = 0;
$keyPattern = 'ccpaRights';

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('section') as $section)
{
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($section->childNodes); $x++)
    {
        $childNode = $section->childNodes[$x];
        $nodeValue = trim($childNode->nodeValue);

        if ($nodeValue === '')
        {
            continue; 
        }

        $count = $count + 1;
        $key = (string) $keyPattern.'Text'.$count;
        
        $vueInterpolation = "{{ \$t(\"$key\") }}";
        
        $newNode = $dom->createElement($childNode->nodeName, $vueInterpolation);

        $childNode->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $childNode);

    }
}


echo $dom->saveHTML($dom);
```

Comment: still getting same results

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand the problem well. I will see it again. Sorry about that

Comment: I updated the answer and I will try to know the reason behind that.

Comment: When you manipulate the dom itself and don't have a fresh perspective of the updated node count, you get trouble.  I have seen many SO answers advise to iterate the array in reverse.  You are creating and replacing nodes, so the count may change each time.  The `for()` counts the nodes before each iteration.